# Java FTPClient - Remote File size 0 bytes VXWorks

Tags: java, ftp-client, vxworks

I am using the apache commons FTP library and attempting to view a file on a USB stick that is running VXWorks. Every time I try to view any file from that system it returns a 0 file size. This works fine when the server is a Windows machine. The code I'm using is:

```
 public synchronized long getRemoteSize(String finalPath)
{
    // Send file and if sent file doesn't match the source file, resend
    try
    {
        FTPFile destinationFile = jh.getFtpClient().mlistFile(finalPath);
        if (destinationFile != null)
        {
            return destinationFile.getSize();
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I have also tried to send a straight SIZE command and it was not recognized. Anyone have any other options or any explanation as to why it always comes back at 0 size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your VXWorks FTP server doesn't support the `MLST` command which is what `mlistFile()` uses under the hood. The `MLST` command was added with [RFC 3659](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3659). In order to use the command the server would need to implement that RFC.

Your best bet is to use the `LIST` command (e.g. [`listFiles(pathName)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html#listFiles(java.lang.String))). This should be the most compatible function of the bunch. This function returns an array instead of a single file, so you'll need to check the return length == 1, but otherwise should be a more-or-less drop in replacement.